# Return a list of words that contain a letter

Tags: python

I wanna return a list of words containing a letter disregarding its case. 
Say if i have `sentence = "Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new"`, then `f(sentence, a)` would return

```
['Anyone', 'has', 'made', 'a', 'mistake', 'has', 'anything']
```

This is what i have

```
import re 
def f(string, match):
    string_list = string.split()
    match_list = []
    for word in string_list:

        if match in word:
            match_list.append(word)
    return match_list
```

Comment: Alright, what’s your question? What is wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `re`. Use `str.casefold`:

```
[w for w in sentence.split() if "a" in w.casefold()]
```

Output:

```
['Anyone', 'has', 'made', 'a', 'mistake', 'has', 'anything']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string splitting for it, if there is not punctuation.

```
match_list = [s for s in sentence.split(' ') if 'a' in s.lower()]
```

Comment: it doesn't produce the correct output, because your solution is not case insensitive.

Comment: Updated for case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation :

```
sentence = 'Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new'

def f (string, match) :
    match_list = []
    for word in string.split () :
        if match in word.lower ():
            match_list.append (word)
    return match_list

print (f (sentence, 'a'))
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  This is so helpful.  All solutions are working well.